# Get pin input status without using the arduino library

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, c++, c, signal-processing

I am not allowed to use the Arduino Library (or any Library) for this program. How would I check the input of a pin?

I found two different functions:

In Arduino.h:

```
#define bitRead(value, bit) (((value) >> (bit)) & 0x01)
```

Following digitalRead back to pgmspace.h:

```
#define __LPM_enhanced__(addr)  \
(__extension__({                \
    uint16_t __addr16 = (uint16_t)(addr); \
    uint8_t __result;           \
    __asm__ __volatile__        \
    (                           \
        "lpm %0, Z" "\n\t"      \
        : "=r" (__result)       \
        : "z" (__addr16)        \
    );                          \
    __result;                   \
}))
```

For the first one, I don't know where bit and value come from and I just don't understand the second one at all.

Comment: This looks a very similar topic to your other recent question: [How do I use masks to make it so pin 13 (PB7 and the LED) as output and then have pin 10 (PB4) as an input?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29861/how-do-i-use-masks-to-make-it-so-pin-13-pb7-and-the-led-as-output-and-then-hav). Please don't ask two very similar questions in the space of a couple of hours.

Comment: I asked this one first to see how to get an input. The other question was to see if use the same Data Port for both an input and an output.

Comment: But it's the same project, right? You are just looking at the same problem in slightly different ways.

Comment: No I'll more than likely use this for every project I do and the other one, it just depends on the project. Where this one is just get any pin. The other question is how to deal with getting an input from the B data registry and changing the state of the light as an output in the same data registry.

Comment: I changed the title of the other question to better describe that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading, e.g., PB2, you would test

```
PINB & _BV(PB2)
```

where PINB is the port input register and `_BV(x)` is a macro defined as
`(1 << (x))`.

C.f. the datasheet for the relevant port names.

See also the Arduino tutorial on
[port manipulation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation).

Comment: Can you explain what (1<< (x)) does please?

Comment: @kingcobra1986: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Bitshift

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean what is a bit shift. I know it is a bit shift to the left by x. What does it do though? Is it for getting the correct pin from the register? Or does it do something else?

Comment: It does exactly what you know it does: it shifts 1 by _x_ places to the left. No more, no less. C.f. http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/BitMath

Comment: @kingcobra1986 The `PB2` is defined as bit position not a bit mask (which is needed for bit manipulation).